# Removing directories excluding parent directories and subdirectories of a folder that contains specific file

Tags: powershell, recursion, directory, parent-child, delete-file

I'm trying to recursively delete all files and subfolders of a directory, except the folders and subfolders that contain `DoNotDelete.txt` file and any of their children (even if they do not have that file).

With a little advice I found in another thread I came up with this solution:

In this example I want to preserve folder E:\testFolder\testF1\blablabla and its children.

```
(Get-ChildItem E:\testFolder -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname) -notlike '*blablabla*' | sort length -descending | remove-item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

The script works as intended only partially - it skips deleting folder 'blablabla' and its children, but still deletes its parent (folder testF1) - which renders the whole endeavour pointless:

> …
>   What if: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "E:\testFolder\testF1".
>   …

How to prevent deletion of the parent and all its direct ancestors in the directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$savedirs = @()

$DoNotDeleteFiles = 
get-childitem E:\testfolders -Recurse -Include donotdelete.txt |
select -ExpandProperty fullname 

foreach ($DoNotDeleteFile in $DoNotDeleteFiles)
 {
   While ($true)
    { 
     Try{
      $savedirs += ($DoNotDeleteFile = $DoNotDeleteFile | Split-Path -Parent -ErrorAction stop )
     }
    catch { Break }
   }
  }


(Get-ChildItem E:\testFolder -recurse | select -ExpandProperty fullname) -notlike '*blablabla*' |
 where { $savedirs -notcontains $_ } |
 sort length -descending | remove-item  -WhatIf
```